# Mapping over constrained existentially qualified higher order type

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, higher-order-types, rank-n-types

I hope I got the terminology right.

I want to do the following:

```
data Hide a = ∀ b. (A.ToJSON (a b), A.ToJSON b) ⇒ Hide (a b)

mapHide ∷ (∀ c. (A.ToJSON (b c), A.ToJSON c) ⇒ a c → b c) → Hide a → Hide b
mapHide f (Hide a) = (Hide $ f a)
```

Unfortunately, GHC seemingly can't infere the constraints right and complains with:

```
Could not deduce (A.ToJSON (b b1)) arising from a use of ‘Hide’
    from the context (A.ToJSON (a b1), A.ToJSON b1)
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Try changing '$' to ordinary parenthesis.

Comment: This is not possible. As suggested by the error message, the function `f` requires a `(ToJSON (b b1))` constraint which is not provided by pattern matching on `(Hide a)`. The "context" in the error message gives the actually provided constraints.
Could you give more details about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Ultimately I got it to work by removing the `A.ToJSON (a b)` constraint, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the function type to something like this might do the trick:

```
 (A.ToJSON (b c2), A.ToJSON c2) ⇒
 (∀ c. (A.ToJSON (a c), A.ToJSON c) ⇒ a c) 
    → b c2)
```

Also avoid using '$' as it kills polymorphism.